# Creating nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am attempting to dynamically create the following using data from an array

```
<li><a href="#" class="red" id="5"><span>Some text</span></a></li>
```

At the moment, I'm creating it in a rather simple way

```
var link = '<li><a href="#" class="' + this.cssClass + '" id="' + this.id + '"><span>' +   this.text + '</span></a></li>';
$('#options').append(link);
```

Although I need a function to be run when the link is clicked, how is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('<a>').attr({
    id: this.id,
    href: '#'
}).addClass(this.cssClass).click(function() {

     // click event

}).html('<span>' + this.text + '</span>')
  .appendTo($('<li>').appendTo('#options'));
```

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do in these situations is create a hidden "template" element on the page that I clone for each element in the array

```
<li id="template"><a href="" class="" id=""><span></span></a></li>
```

then looping through your array and adding these elements

```
$(arr).each(function(i){
    MyObject obj = arr[i];
    var $li = $("#template").clone().removeAttr("id");
    $("a", $li).attr("id", obj.id).addClass(obj.cssClass);
    $("span", $li).text(obj.text);
    $("ul").append($li);
});
```

forgot the link binding portion!!

```
$("ul li a").live("click", function (){
    // DO WORK
});
```

That should bind all of your "a"-click events forever and ever

Comment: this is useful - thanks for sharing. you can replace arr[i] with 'this'

Comment: thanks! You could add a #template { display: none; } css class but I think the prefered method would be to $(document).ready(function(){ $("#template").hide(); });

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. create jquery object from your html
var $li = $(link);

// 2. bind <a> element's click event
$("a", $li).click(function(){
   // your code or a function
});

// 3. place <li> somewhere in html
$("body").append($li);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(link).find('a').click(clickHandlerFunction).end().appendTo('#options');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are building the string is fine (though it might not look as nice as using all the jQuery functions) and will actually perform *faster* than simply using all the jQuery helper functions. How to do it all in one fell swoop is like this:

```
$('<li><a href="#" class="' + this.cssClass + '" id="' + this.id + '"><span>' + this.text + '</span></a></li>')
    .appendTo('#options').find('a').click(function(e){
      // Handle click
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```